# Windows REN command with wildcards doesn't work

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, file-rename

Ok, I know the typical format for the REN command `REN source dest` and there are several examples to rename using wildcards.

Example:

`REN *.txt *.doc`

This will rename all your .txt files to .doc.  Well, this is all fine and dandy, but I have a bunch of files with extensions .aaaa.bbbb and when I use the command:

`REN *.aaaa.bbbb *.aaaa`

I get all of my files with the extenstion .aaaa.aaaa.  Now I cannot come up with a REN command to just get .aaaa extension.

Comment: I think an extension is just the part after the last period, so technically `foo.aaaa.aaaa` just has the extension `aaaa`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ren *.aaaa.bbbb *.
```

For an explanation as to why this works, see [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090)

Comment: Thanks dbenham, that works perfectly!  I cannot vote up your answer because I don't have the reputation but I would if I could.  :)

Comment: @harleygolfguy - but you can accept the answer by clicking on the check mark near the upper left corner. That action lets others know the question has been answered, it awards you 2 rep points, and awards the answer poster 15 points. Only one answer per question can be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

interesting question.
This removes the `.bbbb`:

ren *.bbbb *.

I don't know, why the result is `file.aaaa` and not `file.aaaa.` - but nevertheless, it should solve your problem.

Comment: That will remove the extension from all `.bbbb` files, not just files that match `*aaaa.bbbb`. See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](http://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) for an explanation of how the wildcards work.

Comment: Thanks Stephan and dbenham!